# Trying to clone repo, add a tag and push it back, the tag will appear but my code changes wont

Tags: git, tags

I have a repo with branch master and lots of tags. i would like to pull the code, add a new tag and push the code back to github. then see the code with the new tags and my changes.
the result of what im doing now is just that i see the new tag on the code but the code itself is no different

```
git clone <repo url>
git tag -a 3.0.2 -m "testing"

(now im doing some code changes)
git add .
git commit -m "some changes"
git push origin 3.0.2

im getting output 
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 171 bytes | 171.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://<repourl>....git
 * [new tag]         3.0.2 -> 3.0.2

and now i can see the new tag in the github repo but the code looks the same like the one i clone and does not have my changes in it
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git tag`, when used to create a new tag like this, does exactly that: it creates a new tag.

A tag name, in Git, simply *selects some existing commit*.<sup>1</sup>  Since the commit by definition already exists, there is no change in any code.

If you wish to have different code, you must make the different code (e.g., by changing some existing code) and then *make a commit*.  You can then tag the new commit, if you wish—that's not really required, it's just a way to produce a *human readable and understandable name* for the new commit.  The non-readable raw hash ID also selects that commit, and you can use that instead of the tag (but nobody wants to memorize some big ugly random-looking hash ID!).

You made the tag first, *then* you made some new commits.  That's the wrong order!

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, a tag can tag any of Git's four kinds of objects, but most people only tag commits anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if i change the order to this: git clone, *change code*, git add. , git commit -m "...", git tag -a 3.0.1 -m "changes", git push origin --tags.   
i will see the tag in the repo with my new code, but i will get an error:

This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

Comment: That's not an *error*, that just indicates that the commit you made is not on any branch (in the GitHub side repository). Commits don't have to be on any branch, and many commits are on *many* branches, if you have many branches: what this means is that *branches* in Git are not actually important. It's *commits* that matter. The purpose of a branch name is to help you (and Git) *find* your commits. The purpose of a tag name is to help you (and Git) find one particular commit. These are very similar purposes: the key difference is that the commit a branch name finds *changes over time*.

Comment: Note that the new commit you made is probably on a branch in *your* repository. It's just not on any branch in the *GitHub* repository. Your branches and their branches do not have to match up. It's up to you to decide whether you want the branch names and commit hash IDs to match up, or not.